# List of custom ports for EMR master and slave node

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, hiveql, amazon-emr

I am working on a data project, I am using EMR cluster for data processing 
My AWS environment is restricted it doesn't allow me to use EMR manage security group 
For that, I need a list of custom ports for EMR master and slave node.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-configure.html

Comment: I think this is for Hbase only

Comment: I am using 
Hadoop, Spark, Hive, Tez Hbase , Zookeeper, pig  in EMR

Answer (score 0):

You can see [list of Web Interfaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html) Hosted on Amazon EMR Clusters.

To see what other ports listening on any node

```sh
netstat -tunalp | grep LISTEN
```